# What conditions does the 10750 and 10760 ports need to be exposed in Apache IoTDB docker deployment?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am now studying how to deploy Apache IoTDB on docker. I would like to ask if Apache IoTDB does not need to expose port `10750` and `10760` when mirroring using docker deployment? Since it seems in the user guide that the DataNodes will occupy these two ports, so I want to know if these two ports need to be exposed at all conditions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the stand-alone version of Apache IoTDB, or you want to deploy multiple DataNodes on the same server machine, then these two parts do not need to be exposed. If you are using multiple server machines to deploy a cluster, then these two parts need to be exposed.